# Java running a class that is not in Main class file

Tags: java

I am new to Java and I am trying to make a pong game. I was trying to reference a class file from main (that class file is not inside same file as main) to keep main file cleaner. Is this possible in Java below is what code I have thanks.

Pong.java (Main Class)

```
package pong;

public class Pong {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Pull Frame Class from Frame.java to draw rectangle
    }
}
```

Frame.java (Draws the JFrame)

```
package pong;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Frame extends JPanel {

    public void BoundingBox(Graphics g){
    System.out.print("Java Pong From Frame!!!");
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Welcome to Java Pong");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(800,600);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   

    //Areana border
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect(10,10,773,550);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you should try instantiating a new Frame and rendering it.  Google a Swing tutorial.  One design suggestion: You don't need a Frame class, because you aren't providing any new behavior.  Better to have a panel subclass with your behavior and give it to a JFrame to render.

Comment: Notice how you used classes outside of `Frame` in the `Frame` class?